# AngularJS Jasmine Testing - $scope Variable State Not Saved at End of It Statement?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following function test in Jasmine:

```
describe("myFunction test", function(){
    it("should set $scope.variable to 'test'", function(){
         scope.myFunction("test");
         expect(scope.variable).toBe("test"); //This passes
         console.log(scope.variable); // This logs "test"
    });
    it("should set $scope.variable to null", function(){
         console.log(scope.variable); // Shouldn't this log "test" and not undefined?
         scope.myFunction("test");  
         expect(scope.variable).toBeNull();
    })
});
```

My function in my controller looks like:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(param){
    if(param === $scope.variable){
        $scope.variable = null;
    }
    else{
        $scope.variable = param;
    }
});
```

The function above takes the parameter passed in and compares it against `$scope.variable`.  If the two values match, `$scope.variable` is set to `null`.  Otherwise `$scope.variable` is changed to the parameter's value.

In my Jasmine test, I noticed that after `scope.variable` has been set in an `it` statement, the value isn't carried over to the next `it` statement.  Are `$scope` variables in a Jasmine test not saved every time the `it` statement it was called in comes to an end?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your Jasmine script? What does your injection look like? It may be if your injection is in a `beforeEach` it is being reset because it is re-injecting `scope` before every `it` function.

Comment: @j_buckley I do have a `beforeEach` at the top of the file (before all the individual `describes`) that is creating / injecting controller scope.  I was under the impression that this merely means a new scope is created before each `describe` block, and that within each block, all the `it` statements would still be working against the same set of `scope` variables.  Is this the correct assumption here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beforeEach` affects all following `it` statements, including `it` statements within nested `describe` functions. If your `beforeEach` is at the top it will run before each `it` in your script. You may be able to solve your problem by declaring `scope` before your first `beforeEach` so it is not set as a brand new variable before every `it`. You can also combine your two `it` functions into one so they fall under the same implementation of the `beforeEach`.